# Partition went read-only, how to mount it again?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ext4, umount

Every now and then the partition of my Linux installation goes read-only. Since the computer is a laptop, I suppose it's due to some writing error caused by some harsh movement.

Partition was mounted as:

```
UUID=34h3k4hdf ... /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

How can I make it rw again without re-booting the system or unmounting and re-mounting the partition?

Comment: You may want to check the error by issuing dmesg | grep /dev/sda (if it is sda).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to simply use

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Comment: What if it shows an error like `write protected`?